# Google Analytics Reports: how to remove pageviews for Top Pages and add published date

Tags: 7, views, google-analytics, log-messages

I've installed [google analytics reports](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) to be able to see the most viewed nodes of my website. I were able to add the Top Pages view to my home page but i wanted to know how can i :

1. add published date
2. remove the number count and leave the title only.

See image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking a one difficult task & one simple one. Starting with the simple one (reverse order):

1. The **Top Pages** area is a block that's installed with the module. The *Google Analytics Reports Summary (Google Analytics): Top Pages* view can be configured in the Views UI (**/admin/structure/views/view/google_analytics_reports_summary/edit/attachment_top_pages**). To remove the views count you can click the *Page Tracking: Pageviews* field and use the **Remove** button or **Excluded from display** checkbox to get rid of it.
2. Adding the publish data is a bit harder because what the underlying View is querying. The view is querying data tables from your Google Analytics account. As such, there is no Drupal node data to display from the query. Normally, the Views way to solve this would be to add a relationship with the node table then reference the publish date. However, the module doesn't provide a relationship handler to node content so you're looking a couple things here:

   1. Select a Google Analytics field that can be joined on the node table. *Page Tracking: Page* is a close candidate here as it contains a unique path used for the node link. Nid would be better, but that data isn't sent to Google Analytics by default (you'd have to configure a GA custom variable).
   2. Once you have a selected joined field. You'd have to build your custom relationship handler on which you can join to the node table to retrieve the publish date.

Comment: I were to remove the pageviews count by removing it from display. Trying to remove it was giving me an error. I will look into the 2nd proposed solution. Thanks

Comment: An alternative is to use the **Exclude from display** option that you can set on any field that would prevent any broken references.